# How to mock service on gsp in unit tests

Tags: grails, mocking

I have a template gsp that uses `<g:set var="test" bean="testService">` to get access to a service in the header.

How do I mock/set this service when I'm trying to unit test the template via the `@TestMixin(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)`?

The test is similar to:

```
def renderedView = render(template: '/templates/test')
assert renderedView.contains("test text")
```

When Running the test I get:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag : No bean named 'testService' is defined
        at

```
C__Users_some_name_intellij_project_grails_app_views_templates__test_gsp.run(C__Users_some_name_intellij_project_grails_app_views_templates__test_gsp:24)
        at grails.test.mixin.web.GroovyPageUnitTestMixin.renderTemplateToStringWriter(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin.groovy:166)
        at grails.test.mixin.web.GroovyPageUnitTestMixin.render(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin.groovy:134)
        at project.view.TestTests.myTest(TestTests.groovy:22)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'testService' is defined
        ... 4 more
```

Comment: That's why it's always easier to use (and test) custom tags than trying to call services from within a GSP.

Comment: I understand now, I ended up putting the call in the controller instead and now don't have to worry about it.  I decided that if someone else went on this path an answer might help them.